# Chromecast access raw video/audio data in receiver application

Tags: audio, video, chromecast, google-cast

How can I access/modify the raw data of a video or audio stream in a Chromecast receiver application without rooting the device?

Comment: When you say "rotting the device", what "device" are you referring to?

Comment: I am talking about the chromecast itself

Comment: Within your own app, you have access to the media that your receiver is receiving but that is all; you do not have access to other apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was interested in manipulating a stream from the web on the chromecast itself (Audio EQ for example). I suspected, that this is not possible since the chromecast documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: You can't access other apps (their streams or other aspects of) due to security/privacy issues, as you can imagine.